# Grouping by and counting but retrieve only one column

Tags: sql

The following SQL code returns me two columns: 'product_id' and 'counter'. 
I want it to return only 'product_id', is it possible?

```
select product_id, count(*) as counter
from accounts_products
group by product_id
order by counter DESC
limit 1
```

Comment: You can use Aggregate functions in Order by

Comment: Tag dbms used. (LIMIT is product specific.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `counter` column, and `ORDER BY` the count directly:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM accounts_products
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Additionally, you cannot group or order by the alias column name, Gabriel